# Having trouble running django on Pycharm

Tags: python, django, installation, pycharm

I'm sure you guys have heard enough of these questions but I am a new programmer looking to start using Django. I have done `pip install django` and by the time it's almost done download I received a warning.

WARNING: The script django-admin.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\bryan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.

I have ignored this earlier and ran the command `django-admin startproject` and of course I receive another error.
The term 'django-admin' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program.

Not quite what to do. I need your help. Or at least direct me to a post similar to this matter. Thank you!

I have tried redirecting the PATH with
`pip install--install-option="--prefix=C:\Users\bryan\PycharmProjects\mySite" django`
I saw this on another post and thought it would help but nothing really worked.

Comment: There is no problem with the PyCharm. The problem is with your Python installation. Can you run Python on your machine?

Comment: Yes I can, went to my cmd and typed python.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have globally installed Python with locally installed Python packages.

Option 1: try doing what Windows says: add the directory with locally installed Python packages to the Windows PATH.

Option 2: consider using virtual environments: https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html